# Does the following operator have finite dimensional kernel and cokernel

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the operator T defined on $L^{2}([0,1])$ as

$$(Tf)(t) = tf(t), t \in [0,1]$$

does this operator have finite dimensional kernel and cokernel ?

Comment: Can you write down  the kernel of $T$?

Comment: What is your definition of cokernel?

Comment: The image of $T$ is not closed, it is dense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The image is not dense: if $g(0) = 1$, then no sequence $f_n$ will satisfy $Tf_n \to g$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Let $f \in L^{2}$ and $f_n=fI_{(\frac 1  n ,1)}$. Then $f_n \to f$ and $f_n=T(g_n)$ where $g_n(t)=(f(t)/t)$ for $ t \in (\frac 1  n ,1)$ and $0$ for $ t\leq \frac  1n$. You are thinking of continuous functions but the space here $L^{2}$ the value at a point does not even make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The problem with that construction is that the sequence $g_n$ does not necessarily converge.  In other words, the map $f(t) \mapsto f(t)/t$ is not continuous over $L^2((0,1])$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have written  $f$ as the limit of  sequence $(f_n)$ contained in the range of $T$. Why should $g_n$ converge?

Comment: @Kavi You're completely right, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

The range of $T$ is a proper dense subspace. Let $f \in L^{2}$ and $f_n=fI_{(\frac 1  n ,1)}$. Then $f_n \to f$ and $f_n=T(g_n)$ where $g_n(t)=(f(t)/t)$ for $ t \in (\frac 1  n ,1)$ and $0$ for $ t\leq \frac  1n$.

Comment: There is one problem with the kernel of T as values go from [0,1].

T(f) = 0 implies that f(t) = 0 for all $t \in (0,1])$ how are we sure that f(0) = 0? Notice that function f need not be continuous.

Comment: @TheDude $L^{2}$ consists of equivalence classes of functions. Any function which is $0$ almost everywhere is considered as  the $0$ element of this space.